# Can't enable plugin in rabbitmq 3.7.3

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a web application that receives location data via web sockets. I have installed rabbitmq on my mac via homebrew to run the web sockets locally.  I am trying to enable rabbitmq_web_stomp but I get this error :
`

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp
Error:
{:plugins_not_found, [:rabbitmq_management_visualiser]
```

And when I run `rabbitmq-plugins list`

```
WARNING - plugins currently enabled but missing: rabbitmq_management_visualiser

 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status: * = running on rabbit@localhost
 |/
[E*] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.7.3
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.7.3
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.7.3
[E*] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws       3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common    3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul    3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_etcd      3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s       3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_random_exchange          3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.7.3
[E*] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.7.3
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.7.3
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.7.3
```

But when look at docs https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugins.html
It says rabbitmq_management_visualiser is discontinued and no longer maintained.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should remove rabbitmq_management_visualiser from list of enabled plugins in /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins

Answer (score 0):

Im my case i had an azure container and i discovered plugins were installed under /opt/rabbitmq/plugins instead of /usr/lib/rabbitmq/plugins according with the official guide:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html

I changed the plugins path in the script and i installed the plugin.